# Want To Add Proxy IP In Network Proxy Settings In Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, proxy

I heard that as an additional layer of 'security' it's good in Ubuntu to add a network proxy via settings. I watched this 50 sec vid on how to do that [how to do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJYnvBUJkP8)

Off I went to a free proxy site, got myself one, followed the steps suggested in the via, although Ubuntu 17.10 does not seem to have that 'apply system wide' button, nor was I asked to submit my password, as the case in the vid. Anyhoo after closing the settings panel, with the proxy/ports added, my laptop could not connect to the internet. Hmmmm. I removed the proxy IP and then back online.

I'd like to know if there is a way within Ubuntu 17.10 that can allow me the option of increasing anonymity by adding proxy IP in the Network Proxy settings. But without losing my internet connection. Hope someone out there can help. MR

Comment: A free proxy will not improve your security in any way. Rather it will be detrimental to your security, as it allows an untrusted third party access to all your web traffic.

Comment: I see, thanks, it was an issue I'd not realized

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a VPN, if you do not want to configure it you can use a free vpn, like ProtonVPN whoose free servers vps works well.

[https://account.protonvpn.com](https://protonvpn.com/)

Download the program and follow the instructions to configure it.
You only must to create an account and create a certificate in the web page.

Later import the vpn configuration in the vpn sections in ubuntu.

Comment: I downloaded the VPN for Ubuntu from Private Internet Access and right now my laptop IP is shielded.  So I am guessing that will maintain anonymity. Although I have not set it up within the settings of Ubuntu itself, if that makes any sense? MR